# How to Append to Array of Structs and have Change Persistant?

Tags: swiftui, swift5, swiftui-list

I want to be able to store a list of objects in a separate Swift file and call them in a page to have them show up. I successful did this with this code:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI



struct MatchInfo: Hashable, Codable {
    let theType: String
    let theWinner: String
    let theTime: String
    let id = UUID()
}


var matchInfo = [
MatchInfo(theType: "Capitalism", theWinner: "Julia", theTime: "3/3/2021"),
MatchInfo(theType: "Socialism", theWinner: "Julia", theTime: "3/2/2021"),
MatchInfo(theType: "Authoritarianism", theWinner: "Luke", theTime: "3/1/2021")
]
```

where I append to the list after a match is played on another page here:

```
 matchInfo.insert(MatchInfo(theType: typeSelection, theWinner: winnerName, theTime: "\(datetimeWithoutYear)" + "\(year)"), at: 0)
```

And heres some of the code on another page where I call it into a list:

```
List {
                    ForEach(matchInfo, id: \.self) { matchData in
                        
                        matchRow(matchData : matchData)
                        
                    } .background(Color("invisble"))
                    .listRowBackground(Color("invisble"))
                } .frame(height: 490)
```

...

```
struct matchRow: View {

let matchData: MatchInfo
 
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(matchData.theType)
                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .medium, design: .default))
            Text("    Winner: " + matchData.theWinner)
        }
        Spacer()
    
        Text(matchData.theTime)
            .padding(.leading, 40)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
    
    }
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .accentColor(.white)
}
}
```

But this code doesn't save through app restarts. I've never had something save through a restart before and have been struggling to find an answer simple enough for me to understand. How can I update the list without it going away next time I open the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so here is an example on how you save to/ load from the documents folder.

First of all make sure that you object **MatchInfo** conforms to this protocol.

```
import Foundation

protocol LocalFileStorable: Codable {
    static var fileName: String { get }
}

extension LocalFileStorable {
    static var localStorageURL: URL {
        guard let documentDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
            fatalError("Can NOT access file in Documents.")
        }
        
        return documentDirectory
            .appendingPathComponent(self.fileName)
            .appendingPathExtension("json")
    }
}

extension LocalFileStorable {
    static func loadFromFile() -> [Self] {
        do {
            let fileWrapper = try FileWrapper(url: Self.localStorageURL, options: .immediate)
            guard let data = fileWrapper.regularFileContents else {
                throw NSError()
            }
            return try JSONDecoder().decode([Self].self, from: data)
            
        } catch _ {
            print("Could not load \(Self.self) the model uses an empty collection (NO DATA).")
            return []
        }
    }
}

extension LocalFileStorable {
    static func saveToFile(_ collection: [Self]) {
        do {
            let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(collection)
            let jsonFileWrapper = FileWrapper(regularFileWithContents: data)
            try jsonFileWrapper.write(to: self.localStorageURL, options: .atomic, originalContentsURL: nil)
        } catch _ {
            print("Could not save \(Self.self)s to file named: \(self.localStorageURL.description)")
        }
    }
}

extension Array where Element: LocalFileStorable {
    ///Saves an array of LocalFileStorables to a file in Documents
    func saveToFile() {
        Element.saveToFile(self)
    }
}
```

Your main Content View should look like this: (I modified your object to make it a bit simpler.)

```
import SwiftUI

struct MatchInfo: Hashable, Codable, LocalFileStorable {
    static var fileName: String {
        return "MatchInfo"
    }
    
    let description: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var matchInfos = [MatchInfo]()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Add Match Info:") {
                matchInfos.append(MatchInfo(description: "Nr." + matchInfos.count.description))
                MatchInfo.saveToFile(matchInfos)
            }
            List(matchInfos, id: \.self) {
                Text($0.description)
            }
            .onAppear(perform: {
                matchInfos = MatchInfo.loadFromFile()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, what I meant to say was that I'm successfully able to add to my list and have it show up somewhere else, but don't know how to make it save through app restarts. Is there any chance you can show me how I'd go about that here?

Comment: I updated my answer and added a code example.